# Places API textSearch vs nearbySearch

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api, bounding-box

Here I have a demo that use `nearbySearch` to search for objects inside boxes (route boxer utility):

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_RouteBoxerPlaces.html
CODE:

```
function findPlaces(boxes,searchIndex) {
   var request = {
       bounds: boxes[searchIndex],
       types: ["gas_station"]
   };
   // alert(request.bounds);
   service.radarSearch(request, function (results, status) {
   if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
     alert("Request["+searchIndex+"] failed: "+status);
     return;
   }
   // alert(results.length);
   document.getElementById('side_bar').innerHTML += "bounds["+searchIndex+"] returns "+results.length+" results<br>"
   for (var i = 0, result; result = results[i]; i++) {
     var marker = createMarker(result);
   }
   searchIndex++;
   if (searchIndex < boxes.length) 
     findPlaces(boxes,searchIndex);
   });
}
```

Now when I try to use `textSearch` instead `nearbySearch` I see that code with textSearch and query search for objects outside boxes... http://jsbin.com/ifUZIti/1/edit

```
function findPlaces(boxes,searchIndex) {
   var request = {
       bounds: boxes[searchIndex],
       query: 'gas station'
   };
   // alert(request.bounds);
   service.textSearch(request, function (results, status) {
   if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
     alert("Request["+searchIndex+"] failed: "+status);
     return;
   }
   // alert(results.length);
   document.getElementById('side_bar').innerHTML += "bounds["+searchIndex+"] returns "+results.length+" results<br>"
   for (var i = 0, result; result = results[i]; i++) {
     var marker = createMarker(result);
   }
   searchIndex++;
   if (searchIndex < boxes.length) 
     findPlaces(boxes,searchIndex);
   });
}
```

What is difference beetween `textSearch` and `nearbySearch` and WHY when I try to use textSearch code search and looking for objects outside defined boxes ? What is problem here?
with `nearbySearch` all works fine but I can't use query with nearbySearch so I must use textSearch but with `textSearch` script search objects outside boxes ?
How I can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you zoom in on the places that look like they are way outside the box on a high level rendering, you will see they are all either well inside the box, or just out side the box. It isn't nearly as bad as it looks at first blush. See [my version of your code](http://jsbin.com/IYovow/2/edit?html,output) to see the results.